# How to pass a caption as an argument of newenvironment

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, arguments

I make a next newenvironment to insert the code of a tikzfigure in the document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{minted}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usetikzlibrary{babel, arrows, external, calc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codeframe}{HTML}{2A7E43}
\definecolor{codeback}{HTML}{2B2E32}

\newenvironment{exampleTikz}
  {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \begin{VerbatimOut}{example.out}}
  {\end{VerbatimOut}
   \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
   \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
   \inputminted[
   style = friendly,
    fontsize=\footnotesize,
    resetmargins, 
    frame = lines,
    framesep = 2mm, 
    baselinestretch = 1.2,
    bgcolor = codeback!15,
    linenos
 ]{latex}{example.out}
\end{minipage}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
  \input{example.out}
\end{figure}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Un vector}

\begin{exampleTikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
scale = .75,
vector/.style = {>=latex, ->, line width = 1.5pt},
]
\tkzInit[xmin = -1, xmax = 4, ymin = -1, ymax = 4]
\tkzDrawXY[noticks]
\draw[vector] (0, 0) -- (2, 3);
\tkzPointShowCoord[xlabel = $2$, ylabel = $3$, color = gray!50](2, 3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{exampleTikz}

\end{document}
```

The result should be

[image]

but I want pass as an argument the caption to the figure, then the question is, how I can pass the caption of the figure as an argument of the newenvitonment.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Skillmon - I'm always happy to upvote a working answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The following approach can work:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\newenvironment{mypicture}[2][]%
{%
  \def\mypicturetemp{#2}%
  \begin{figure}[#1]%
    \centering%
}{%
    \caption{\mypicturetemp}%
  \end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{mypicture}{foo}
  \rule{1em}{1em}
\end{mypicture}
\end{document}
```

I used this MWE since your provided code can't be run on my machine, since it lacks the `\documentclass` and `\usepackage`s.